# Is anyone developing with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm currently considering a big "no no" and jumping over to VS 2010 while it's still in RC... after all, text code is text code, how bad can it "F" things up?

I'm just wondering if anyone is using VS 2010 for their projects?  I'm very much interested in the subtle additions as well as the multi-screen support.

Comment: Yes. Many people are. It has a Go Live license...

Comment: Is it stable enough to work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using it in a VM and it's been pretty stable and even resharper 5.0 has support for it now so it's as good as fully baked for my liking.

A few things to be careful of are:

- the .sln files aren't backwards compatible so it won't be easy to share with other people not using VS2010.
- There are a number of plugins that don't yet support VS2010 so if you depend on any third party plugins make sure they work
- ASP.NET MVC 2 RC 2 has a bit of funkiness so you should check out [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/10/installing-asp-net-mvc-2-rc-2-on-visual-studio.aspx) to make sure you've got all your stars aligned if you're using 2010 and MVC.

Comment: I'm not using MVC, I do use Telerik Rad Controls and a couple of other components, and I don't share my solutions... should be good :)  I do use ReSharper, VisualSVN, and a few other on off dll's.

Comment: Question: If I develop a project and need to run it live, I obviously need to install the .NET 4 Framework (Beta) on my production server... no issues there either?

Comment: you only need to install the .net 4 framework if you're compiling against .net 4. If you're not using the 4 features, I'd stick to compiling against 3.5

Answer (score 0):

As you said first of all it is still in RC. People wouldn't upgrade the current Visual Studio version unless there is a reason for it.

If you are not going to use any of the features in .net 4.0, it is probably not important to switch to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I guess you mean that VS2010 doesn't ready yet, and not vs2008 :)

Comment: I do want the features... namely dual monitor support.

Answer (score 0):

We are using VS2010RC and TFS2010 for our projects in production.
Works great!!

What I like in VS2010 and use:

- Test Manager for recording manual tests in Web, WPF, Windows Forms and soon in Silverlight. AWESOME!
- Generating "Coded UI" tests
- Hierarchical work items (TFS) *finally :-)*

What I like in VS2010 **but don't use yet**:

- .NET4 features like: Parallel extensions, dynamic keyword, optional and named parameter

Yes, Multi Monitor support works a bit better, but was fine for me with VS2008 too

Comment: I would definitely need some more info on Hierarchical work items, parallel extensions, dynamic keywords... I'm not that "advanced".  Did you have to install the .NET 4 framework on your production server?